# File.Copy mystery

Tags: c#, file-io

I have the following code (actually divided among various methods, but this is what it amounts to):

```
string ThePath = FBD.SelectedPath; // FBD is a FolderBrowserDialog.
string TheSubDirPath = Path.Combine(ThePath, TheSubDirName);
if (Directory.Exists(TheSubDirPath)) {      Directory.Delete(TheSubDirPath, true); } // Want a clean, empty directory.
Directory.CreateDirectory(TheSubDirPath);
string TheSrcFileName = Path.Combine(ThePath, MyOldFileName);
string TheDestFileName = Path.Combine(TheSubDirPath, MyNewFileName);
File.Copy(TheSrcFileName, TheDestFileName, false); // Overwriting is impossible, so not needed.
```

This last line is causing a DirectoryNotFoundException with the message

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users...\Test01\TheSubDirName\MyNewFileName'."

Both the source and destination paths are exactly what I want them to be.
I have tried inserting delays after the directory deletion and after the directory creation, to no effect. I have a stack trace which shows the heart of the problem

> at
>       System.IO.Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>
> at
>       System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
>
> at
>       System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)

Any ideas?

Comment: What are the values of both `TheSrcFileName` and `TheDestFileName`?

Comment: Your code works correctly for me, even with three dots in `c:\users...\dunsany`. Please share enough information for us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: What if `TheSubDirPath` already exists as something other than a directory?

Comment: TheSrcFileName is "C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Test01\filename.ext"

Comment: TheDestFileName is C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Test01\subdirname\anotherfilename.ext"

Comment: TheSubDirPath does not exist as anything other than TheDestFileName (without the filename).

Answer (score 1):

Potentially there might be a situation when 
 a result of calling the method `Directory.Delete(TheSubDirPath, true)` might leave the folder as 'to be removed'. So potentially, you might have removed folder after creating a new one. Try to change the statement

```
if (Directory.Exists(TheSubDirPath))
        Directory.Delete(TheSubDirPath, true);
```

with

```
while(Directory.Exists(TheSubDirPath))
{
    Directory.Delete(TheSubDirPath, true);
    Sleep(); //Somehow like Thread.Sleep()
}
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed it! Many thanks to you all!’while (Directory.Exists(TheSubPath)){Directory.Delete(TheSubPath.true);Thread.Sleep(1000);}

Answer (score 0):

replace if condition with :

```
if (Directory.Exists(TheSubDirPath))
    Directory.Delete(TheSubDirPath, true);
```